# Count number of elements in an array in javascript (not length)

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, count

I've got an array with different "columns", for example: id, title, date, data etc.

It is a JSON array.

The data element has multiple entries:

```
"data":["test = test", "2nd test", "3rd test"]
```

How can I find how many entries there are in the "data" element of the "result" array?
When I try `result.data.length`, it gives me the whole length, so all the characters.
Here, it would say something like 27, while I want 3 as an answer.

EDIT: this is how I get the elements and push them (I get a JSON array):

```
$.getJSON("test.php?id=" + id, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, data1) {               
        window.result.push(data1);  
    });
```

And this is the test.php code:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id = $_GET['id'];
$liste = getData($id);
$arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($liste as $result){
    $arr[$i]['id'] = $result->id();
    $arr[$i]['titre'] = $result->titre();
    $arr[$i]['data'] = $result->listeMot();
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's something you're not telling us, because JavaScript doesn't behave that way: `result = {"data":["test = test", "2nd test", "3rd test"]}; result.data.length; // 3`. We can't help you without seeing the actual code, because the code you've posted cannot behave the way you say it does.

Comment: I agree with @meagar -- can you post the console log output of your object?

Comment: If the `data` field is an Array as you say it is, it will not report `27` instead of `3`, it will report `3`.

Comment: Is `result.data` an array or a string?

Comment: Sounds like `data` is actually a string.  How are you creating this "array"?  Did you forget to `JSON.parse` it?

Comment: How are you creating this?  Did you convert the array to JSON *before* you added it to the object?

Comment: In the beginning, it is a JSON array on another PHP page. I get it by using JSON and I store it in a window.result array, by using "push". From that window.result, I retrieve the elements in different functiond and I store them in a variable. Is this more clear? Sorry for that.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes I convert an array to JSON before I add it to the object. Is it a string then?

Comment: @YannickBloem: Yep.  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  There is no such thing as a "JSON array" (or "JSON object").  When you convert to JSON you are creating a string.  A string that can be converted back into an array/object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Very interesting, thanks for that. Is there any way for me to still count it the way I'm doing this?

Comment: @YannickBloem: Can you show us the `test.php` file?

Comment: It could be that the `data` property contains a string (I'm not sure what  `$result->listeMot()` returns). If that's the case, you can fix it with `$arr[$i]['data'] = explode(',', $result->listeMot());` on the PHP side, or `window.result.push(data1.split(','));` on the js side.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was finally found (thanks a lot  to @RocketHamzat).
It was indeed a string, and not an array. In that case, I had returns after each pair of words (I thought they were separated by commas, but they weren't).

So, to count, this is what I did:

```
result.data.split('\r\n').length;
```

This worked like a charm. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments posted - your return object does not look as if it is formatted properly. data should be an object with a key value of the array. Your return should look like the following:

```
var d = '{"data":["test = test", "2nd test", "3rd test"]}';
console.dir(JSON.parse(d));
var arr = JSON.parse(d);
console.log(arr.data.length);
```

The console.dir will display the object, and the console.log displays a length of 3.

Are you formatting the response as a JSON string manually? If so wrap with {}

Hope that helps.